# Can Patrician 2 be played on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, patrician-ii

I am considering buying [Patrician 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005NURQ) but it needs Windows XP.

Will it work on Windows 7 or [legacy mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851564.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have the gold edition (which has been marketed as Patrician 3 in the US but is Patrician 2 with the add-on Rise of the Hanse) and it runs perfectly on Windows 7 on my PC.

Comment: Since this next question is subjective, I won't ask it as a separate question. Do you like the trading system? That is the part I am interested in playing.

Comment: I personally like it, yes. It's not all too complex in the beginning, you basically keep driving from town to town and load your ship with whatever is in high stock and bring it back to another city, until you have some starting money. From there you can build your own production and more ships for more trading. I have never played it very long to know how it plays past that, but I had a lot of fun for quite a few hours. If you don't have it already, I suggest you get Patrician 3 though, because it has the add-on included.